# Get empty result when I push array into array in recursive

Tags: javascript

```js
var subsets = function(nums=[1,2,3]) {
    nums.sort( (a, b) => a - b);
    
    return dfs(nums, 0, [], []);
};

var dfs = function(nums, pos, tmp, res) {
    if(nums.length === pos) {
        res.push(tmp.slice());
        return;
    }

    // 選
    tmp.push(nums[pos]);
    dfs(nums, pos+1, tmp, res);

    // 不選
    tmp.pop()
    dfs(nums, pos+1, tmp, res);

    return res;
}

console.log(subsets());
```

I want to find all subsets of nums.
If nums=[1, 2, 3], I hope output is [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

In my code,`tmp` is a subset of `nums`, and `res` is used to save all possible `subsets` of nums.

In the 9 line, if I write `res.push(tmp)`, then I will print empty array.
But if I write `res.push(tmp.slice())`, I can print array with values.

```
if(nums.length === pos) {
    console.log(tmp);
    console.log(tmp.slice());
    res.push(tmp.slice());
    return;
}
```

If I print both `tmp` and `tmp.slice()` like above, they both have same value.

I am so confused, how to explain this situation?

Maybe in recusive, res array doesn't reuse value ?

Comment: What is `tmp`? What is `res?` This needs a little more detail.

Comment: Can you please update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Instead, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76273545/edit) your question to include the original source code in text format marked down as code, or better yet, since it is JavaScript, as a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), Array.prototype.slice() returns a **shallow copy** of the array being sliced. If you want to push a shallow copy to the result array, you could replace the line containing the slice method with:

`res.push([...tmp]);`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `tmp` to `dfs` in the recursive call (e.g. `dfs(nums, pos+1, tmp, res)`), no copy of it is made; you're essentially passing a reference to that array and thus `tmp` always refers to the same one array throughout the execution of the program. Consequently, `res.push(tmp)` always adds the same one array to `res`, so at the end you end up with multiple references to the same array in `res`.

After `dfs` is complete, `tmp` is cleared because all elements are popped. `res` consists of multiple references to `tmp` which all reflect changes to that array, so you see an array containing multiple empty arrays.

[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) makes a shallow copy of the array, so `res.push(tmp.slice())` will add a different array each time, avoiding the issue.